# Mysql command line window does not open

Tags: mysql, installation

[image: This is a screenshot of error dialog after trying to start mysql57 from Task Manager[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byfnd.png)I installled mysql I thought successfully, but when I try to open the command line client for i, it opens for a split second then closes, as with other people on Stack Overflow.

When going to Task Manager > Services tab and trying to start Mysql, I get the error with “Access denied”. So I followed up with someone's advice to go to Control Panel/Admin Tools and try to start Mysql there. I get the following error window!

Services (on title bar)
“The mysql service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.”

OK button bottom right.

Sorry I could not paste the error window here!

I wonder what the solution would be now.

Thanks in advance,
M

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to follow using Windows command-line:

- Open `cmd` as administrator :
- 1 - type `mysql server path on your computer. ex: c:\programms files\MySql\MySql Server 8.0\bin`
- 2 - type `MySQL --install`
- 3 - type `MySQL --initialize`

Answer (score 0):

Now there are couple of steps you have to follow. As there seems a installation or configuration error.

Firstly remove MySQL from your device fully. Uninstall from control panel. Delete files from drive where it made a folder while installing.

Reinstall MySQL from very beginning.

There are other options using regedit tooling and stuffs also.

Other problem with it I can feel is some other process is not letting it executed. So you can kill the process using command prompt and then start it again.

But for now I would recommend just reinstall it and do nothing parallel while installing it. After installation just restart your device and it'll work for sure.

Still if you have trouble I'm here for sure.

Comment: Hi Chirag, Thanks for your reply and apologies for long gap of time since - I tried that but it did not help! Also I had the same problem with two other computers.  The errors from last attempt (a few days ago) are as below.  Please attempt to pinpoint precise issue in order to specify a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Precisely, I would like to help you. Kindly send me images of your errors and I'll respond you with an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

FOR THE BENEFIT OF OTHERS:

I tried to delete all files in Mysql folders and uninstalled all mysql programs (except Connector .NET which was not possible) then tried to reinstall mysql.

I m actually getting an error during the configuration of Mysql Server (screenshot below) - ALL other steps were configured correctly, o it is defo this step that is causing the error.

I also tried very briefly stopping my Firewall, but that did not help either.

The below is the info in the configuration log file, if it makes sense to anyone.

```
Beginning configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]
Ended configuration step: Stopping Server [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating firewall
Adding firewall rule for MySQL80 on port 3306.
Successfully added firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating firewall

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]
Deleting Data folder shipped
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --Initialize-insecure
Running process: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
Waiting for the server stops: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --initialize-insecure=on --console
2018-09-10T19:31:39.510737Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-09-10T19:31:39.510737Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-09-10T19:31:39.526337Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-09-10T19:31:39.526337Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
The attempt to initialize the database Failed
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database [if necessary]

Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
Starting MySQL as a service
```

[image: Error message screenshot DURING Mysql Server configuration]